# Wrong site title and description in google search

Tags: title, conditional-tags, seo, description, google-search

as i said in the topic, i can't change the title and the description of the google search of my website (new website btw). I tried to change the title by Theme description, by wordpress settings and also using Yoast Seo Plugin, but nothing worked and i still see a chinese (?) description in the title and tag.

Anyone know how to fix it?

Thank you in advance

This is what i mean: https://imgur.com/a/6DfbyTn

Comment: Please upload images directly into the post, for improved accessibility and security.

Answer (score 0):

Your site's homepage has no description set. Since I see you are using a static page for the homepage, ensure that you are providing a description using Yoast SEO plugin when editing the page. Anyway, as in the screenshot, the homepage is not updated by Google (It takes sometime to update).

Answer (score 0):

Google indexes your site on its own timeline. If you have [Google Search Console](https://search.google.com/search-console/about) set up for your site, you can request that Google re-index your site. Once it does, your search listing will update according to the information you've provided via Yoast.